# IE8 select population performance issues - solutions needed

Tags: html, dom, internet-explorer-8

I have an application that is having issue when populating selects with over 100 items.  This problem only occurs in IE8.  I am using angularjs to do the population, but my research shows that this is a general problem with IE8.  What solutions have others used to deal with this problem.  We have over 40,000 users tied to IE8 for the foreseeable future (Fortune 200 company) so moving to another browser is not an option.

Some thoughts I had.

- Create a series of option tags as a one long string in memory and replace the innerHTML of the .  But running some people samples this does not appear to solve the issue.
- Originally populating the select with a few  and then adding the rest as the user scrolls down.  I am not sure if this is possible, or how to implement this

I am sure others have run into this issue.   Does anyone have some ideas?

Thanks,

Jerry

Comment: Would you be able to use a styled `ul`? http://jsfiddle.net/kjnbZ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution seems to be to create the Select and it's options as a text string and add that string as the innerHTML of the containing tag such as a DIV.  Below is some code.

```
<div id="selectHome" ></div>
```

In JS (from angular controller)

```
   function insertSelect(divForSelect) {
       var str = "<select id='myselect'>";
       for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          str += '<option>' + data[i] + '</data>';
       }
       str += '</select>';
       divForSelect.innnerHTML = str;
   }
```

Note that inserting options into a existing Select is very slow (8,000 msecs for 2000 items).  But, if the select and the options are inserted as a single string it is very fast (12 msec for 2000 items).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that preserves the original `<select>` is to set the `<option>` values *after* adding the options to the `<select>`.

### Theory

1. Add the `<option>` elements to a document fragment.
2. Add the document fragment to the `<select>`.
3. Set the value for each `<option>`.

### Practice

In practice we end up with a couple issues we have to work around to get this to work:

1. IE11 is very slow when setting the value for each individual `<option>`.
2. IE8 has selection bugs because it isn't properly doing a re-flow/layout on the `<select>`.

### Result

To handle these what we *really* do is something like the following:

1. Add the `<option>` tags to a document fragment. *Make sure to set the values so that step 3 is a no-op in IE11.*
2. Add the document fragment to the `<select>`.
3. Set the value for each `<option>`. *In IE8 this will set the values, in IE11 this is a no-op.*
4. In a `setTimeout` add and remove a dummy `<option>`. *This forces a re-flow.*

### Code

```js
function setSelectOptions(select, options)
{
    select.innerHTML = ''; // Blank the list.
  
// 1. Add the options to a document fragment.
    var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragement();
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
    {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.text = options[i];
        docFrag.appendChild(opt);
    }
  
// 2. Add the document fragment to the select.
    select.appendChild(docFrag);
  
// 3. Set the option values for IE8. This is a no-op in IE11.
    for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
        select.options[i].text = options[i];

// 4. Force a re-flow/layout to fix IE8 selection bugs.
    window.setTimeout(function()
    {
        select.add(document.createElement('option'));
        select.remove(select.options.length - 1);
    }, 0);
}
```